# Commenting on GitHub PR in WebStorm

Tags: github, webstorm

I've been used to using the great BitBucket PR plugin in WebStorm, but my new company uses GitHub. With the GitHub plugin I can definitely view the PR, but I can't seem to comment on it.

Is there a way to comment from WebStorm, or another better plugin that will let me?